# Array give [object object] after pushing object inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The array show as [object object] after I push the object inside it even though the object that are inside the array show up as what I want it to be . I tried searching google and YouTube but didn't find anything

```
let arr = []
let list = ""
let rev = {}
const btn = document.getElementById("savel")
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
                 val1 = name.value
                 val2 = age.value
                shh ()                              
                console.log(val1)
})

function shh () {
     rev = {
                names: val1,
                ages: val2
}
showname.textContent = rev.names
showage.textContent = rev.ages
   arr.push(rev)
   console.log(arr)
   uul ()
}

function uul () {
                for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                                list = arr[i]
                }
                ul.innerHTML += `
                <li> ${list} </li>
                `
}
console.log(rev)
```

Comment: So... why is that a problem?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Here are some [helpful guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254573/979052) you might find useful, regarding your question.

Comment: That's what happens when you call `toString` on an object... what do you want the output to be?

Comment: @MajorProductions I want to make a form where the value of the input tag will go to the object then I push the object to an array and show that array  back in my html page but it show [object object] instead of the thing I write in the input field

Answer (score 0):

You're appending to the `list` array after the for loop ends.
Change the `uul` function to:

```
function uul () {
    for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        list = arr[I];
        ul.innerHTML += '<li> ${list} </li>';
    }           `
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

If I have the following array and I try to show it in an alert

```
var myArray = [{name: "Jack"}, {name: "John"}];
alert(myArray);
```

The output will be `[object Object],[object Object]`,

But if I use `JSON.stringify`:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(myArray))
```

the output will be `[{"name":"Jack"},{"name":"John"}]`.

The same logic applies to your code and into the `ul.innerHTML`. Read more about [here](https://sebhastian.com/javascript-print-array/).

Comment: I have figured this out . The problem is actually because I use only object and not object.something